# Getting ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation while trying to create record with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create a record with associations.

```
class Migration < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  create_table "users", id: :serial do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"

    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "profiles", id: :serial do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "profile_type", default: 0, null: false

    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_profiles_on_user_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "profiles", "users"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  with_options presence: { message: "can't be blank" } do
    validates :first_name, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 20 }
    validates :last_name, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50 }
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
  user = User.new(first_name: "first_name", last_name: "last_name")
  user.build_profile
  user.save
end
```

Sometimes I get an error
`ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "profiles" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_057a5c93f0" DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(:some_id) is not present in table "users".` But I am not quite sure what the issue is. I expect the transaction rollback after inserting into `users` if there is any issue.

rails 6.1.5; ruby 3.1.2; postgres 12

Comment: Is it required to have a foreign key with a has_one relationship? And why use an integer instead of `references` In the profiles table?